# Symfony translation with placeholder doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, twig, translate

I'm trying to translate my app with Symfony translate (5.1.*). I use Symfony 5.1.
Basic translation work fine but I have problem with variable in twig.

When I do
`{% trans with {'%name%': 'World'} from 'app' %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}`

It works fine and the result is *Hello World* as expected. But if I do

```
php bin/console translation:update --force en
php bin/console cache:clear
```

to generate the translation file, the result is *Hello %name%*.

If in the translation file, I delete this reference:

```
<trans-unit id="yhpYN0i" resname="Hello %name%">
    <source>Hello %name%</source>
    <target>Hello %name%</target>
</trans-unit>
```

the result is again *Hello World*.

Anybody has any idea why the translation file doesn't work when using a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [ICU message format](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#message-placeholders), the placeholders have to be `{}`. As the documentation states:

> In the previous translation format, placeholders were often wrapped in
> % (e.g. %name%). This % character is no longer valid with the ICU
> MessageFormat syntax, so you must rename your parameters if you are
> upgrading from the previous format.

You'd have to change your translation file to:

```
<target>Hello {name}</target>
```

And remove `%` from your twig helper call

```
{% trans with {'name': 'World'} from 'app' %}Hello %name%{% endtrans %}
```

To keep using the old format if you don't need the pluralization rules provided by ICU you can rename the translation file to remove the `+intl-icu` suffix.

Comment: Doesn't the translated text should also replace the `%` with `{}`?
Like `Hello {name}`?

Comment: @tcit Do you mean inside the `trans` tag? IIRC, no, it's not necessary, it's used like a literal and not interpolated, just to lookup the translation. If you look closely at the `source` tag it still has `%name%` in it. This requires the least amount of work, that string is just a literal; you could've just as well used `say_hello`, as the example in the docs. I'd have to double-check to be 100% sure, but I _think_ that's accurate.